# Grassmanian is a manifold (Hirsch)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, problem-solving, grassmannian

I am trying to do an exercise from Hirsch's Book , Differential Topology, that basically wants me to prove that $G_{n,k}$ is a manifold.

> The Grassmanian manifold $G_{n,k}$ of $k$-dimensional subspaces or $k-$planes of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given an atlas as follows. Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $k-$plane ,  we can identify $\mathbb{R}^n\cong E\bigoplus E^\perp$ . Every $k$-plane near enough $E$ is the graph of a unique linear map $T:E\rightarrow E^{\perp}$.

Now I don't see why this statement is true and how this is going to give me an open set, can anyone provide me some hints ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using this atlas to define the topology on $G_{n,k}$, or have you already defined the topology elsewhere?

Comment: For starters, what linear map $T$ gives you the subspace $E$ itself? Do you see how to get every $k$-plane that projects isomorphically onto $E$ as the graph of some such $T$?

Comment: In Loring's book "introduction to manifolds", chapter 2, section 7, problems, appears that problem but divided in steps (and with hints) that will help you to solve the problem by your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: You can interpret "$F$ is close enough to $E$" as "$F\cap E^\perp=\{0\}$" and the subspaces with this property define the open neighborhood of $E$ that you are looking for. Assuming this, any elment of $\mathbb R^n$ can be uniquely written as the sum of an element of $F$ and an element of $E^\perp$. Doing this for elements of $E$ and then mapping to the $E^\perp$-component defines a linear map $E\to E^\perp$, whose graph is $F$. Since the space $L(E,E^\perp)$ of linear maps is a finite dimensional vector space, you can construct charts as having values in this space. (Alternatively, choose bases and interpret charts as having values in spaces of matrices.)